# getDate() returns a day before the actual date

Tags: date, timezone, js

another issue with dates not working properly. I have a date field on my object. When selecting a date, I am using this in my js.

```
let sDate = new Date(this.opportunity.data.fields.Start_Date__c.value);
```

The value is returning this:

```
"2021-05-01T00:00:00.000Z"
```

Which is good!

Than, I need to get the month by using `getMonth()`. It will work for any days I selected in the date field except the first day of the month. It will return the previous month. I used `getDate()` to see why and it seems to display the previous day.

```
let sDate = new Date(this.opportunity.data.fields.Start_Date__c.value);
console.log(JSON.stringify(sDate)); //  "2021-05-01T00:00:00.000Z"
        
let date1 = sDate.getDate();
console.log(JSON.stringify(date1)); // 30
```

I though about adding +1 to the date but it will not be smart... I need to understand why it does that?
My local timezone is eastern time NY the default timezone under company info is also eastern time... Not sure where to look at...
Thanks

Comment: Getddate returns the date in your local timezone, so relative to gmt time you are still on april 30th.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate

Comment: Also to note, both getMonth() and getUTCMonth() are 0 based. So 0 is actually the first month - January, while 11 is the 12th month - December.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I guess that I have to use `getUTCMonth()` to make it work...